# Kafka topics not created after initial batch load

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a running instance of landoop fast data dev docker container which has sqlserver as source and s3 as the sink. The source configuration is

```
name=JdbcSourceConnector
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1    
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver:/hostname.com.au:1433;databaseName=DB;user=;password=
topic.prefix=activitylog
timestamp.column.name=DateTimeStamp
query=Select * from dbo.activitylog
mode=timestamp 
table.types=VIEW
poll.interval.ms=5000
batch.max.rows=1000
```

Once the s3 sink is configured, I can see the around 1000 rows immediately written to s3,but after that nothing happens.My source has got thousands of rows but the producer is not producing any more topics after the first run. 
Is there any configuration further to be done in order for the producer to create topics continuously?

S3 sink connection looks like this

```
name=S3SinkConnector
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector
topics=activitylog
tasks.max=1
format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.avro.AvroFormat
flush.size=3
s3.bucket.name=testbucket
storage.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage
s3.region=ap-southeast-2
s3.part.size=5242880
partitioner.class=TimeBasedPartitioner
path.format= YYYYMMdd_HH
timezone=AEST
```

Please help.

Comment: You don't need to use `query` if you're doing a `SELECT *`. See https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector for more detail, and also https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector#why-no-data specifically

Comment: Ignoring S3 for the moment, what do you get in your topic from the JDBC source? Just 1000 rows? I'd focus on that, before complicating things with additional moving parts (the S3 sink) :)

Comment: Thanks for the link , I will have a look. If I look at the topics UI I can see around 160 topics. It doesn't grow beyond this.

Comment: you'll only get one topic per object in the database

Comment: You are right, one topic and 160 messages .. is there a way to find out what sql is being fired at the back ground  from logs. I am trying to get the sql from Sql Server profiler though.

Comment: Yes, bump up the logging on Kafka Connect to `DEBUG`. See https://rmoff.net/2019/01/29/kafka-connect-change-log-level-and-write-log-to-file/